# Conditional formatting

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, conditional-formatting

What I am looking to do is have a conditional format set up so that if row G contains the value "In progress" "With 3rd Party" or "Identifying" and row H, J or K contain no value then highlight rows A to L in red. (or just highlight the entire row in red if it is not possible to specify that many individual cells in red).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using condition format based on formula.

Select A to L columns, add a new conditional formatting rule (`Conditional formatting` > `New rule...` > `Use a formula to determine which cells to format`) and enter the following formula:

```
=AND(OR($G1="In progress";$G1="With 3rd Party";$G1="Identifying");OR(ISBLANK($H1);ISBLANK($J1);ISBLANK($K1)))
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have tried this and it comes back with "The formula yout typed contains an error."

Comment: Does te formula work if you type this exact same formula in M1 cell?

Comment: It just shows the value of the cell as =AND(OR($G1="In progress";$G1="With 3rd Party";$G1="Identifying");OR(ISBLANK($H1);ISBLANK($J1);ISBLANK($K1)))

Comment: Can you try this formula please? `=AND(OR($G1="In progress",$G1="With 3rd Party",$G1="Identifying"),OR(ISBLANK($H1),ISBLANK($J1),ISBLANK($K1)))`